# Hd wallet address generator with ethereum

Tags: cryptography, ethereum

Hy everyone,

I'm doing a hd wallet generator (normal child) with only use xpub key. Therefore, can someone help me pls. With library of golang or main flow of generating from: (xpub key, index) -> ethereum address

Example:

```
- Master public key
  xpub661MyMwAqRbcEchqhvjmDox2feNsqWwWTw4hWTemBx9asYS8r9SYKUkZr4a2DkEE7UpeZMhqcX4EsxDpEQBJTjn2ytnZ5EBnj6H8gf4S9P6

- index: 0 (or path m/0)
  0xB6ff335fa47F0e3dC6491f21a02527dDc3bd21d3
```

Comment: Tin, did you solve your problem? I actually have exactly the same question, but for java (bitcoinj/web3j libs)